# Embeber vídeos en web sin que salga la barra de reproducción en ningún sitio

Tags: html5, video

Necesito embeber un vídeo en mi web y que se reproduzca automáticamente sin que aparezca la barra de reproducción, es decir, que el vídeo no se puede pausar, ni echar hacia adelante, ni nada.

He probado con este código:

```
<video src="video.mp4" autoplay>
```

Pero en móvil siempre aparece la barra.

¿Habría alguna forma de que no apareciera dicha barra y que el video se reprodujera de principio a fin sin que lo puedan alterar?

Comment: Nasko, alguna de las soluciones te ha sido util ? ^^ Si es asi, recuerda aceptar la que consideres como aceptada. Un saludo

Comment: Si alguna pregunta te fue de utilidad recuerda marcarla como aceptada. si no, qué fallos o problemas tienes ? Un saludo

Answer (score 2):

Puedes añadir CSS para que no se vean los controles:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls {
    display: none;
}
```

Ej:

```css
video::-webkit-media-controls {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<video width="300" autoplay >
  <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

<sub>Sacado de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36293084/3045491)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

De esta manera, a mi no me salen los controles en mi Smartphone:

```html
<video width="300" height="200" autoplay="autoplay">
<source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Por otro lado, siempre puedes indagar para poder ocultar los botones y los elementos de navegación del reproductor mediante CSS. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo para ocultar el botón de `pause`, `fullscreen`... por ejemplo:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button, video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button, video::-webkit-media-controls-pausebutton {
    display: none;
}
```